# dynamically change the name attribute of an element

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery function that takes the following html from a page using this:

```
//get html
var myHtml = $("#info").html()
```

Here's the html it gets:

```
    <div id="info">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="tbAnswer" value="Feedback..." /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to change the name of the textbox name attribute to follow a counter.  So it would look like this **name="tbAnswer1"**

I tried this:

```
$(document).on('ready', function () {
    $("info").closest("input").attr("name", "tbAnswer" + myCounter);
});
```

But it's not finding it.

Is there a way of doing this with jQuery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot your `#`:

```
$("#info").find("input").attr("name", "tbAnswer" + myCounter);
```

And you want `find`, not `closest`.  `find` gets descendants, which `input` is.

Comment: And `input` is a descendent of `#info` in OP's code, not a parent.

Comment: @Dogbert Yup, edited that in already.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `#` before `id`

```
$(document).on('ready', function () {
    $("#info").find("input").attr("name", "tbAnswer" + myCounter);
});
```